# What specific limitations does GIMP have compared to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, cc-2019

I am considering switching to GIMP. I would like to know how GIMP compares to Photoshop in terms of functions overall. Are there things that Photoshop can do, that GIMP cannot?

Comment: Hi Franco and welcome to GDSE! I've edited your question, please let me know if this is what you would like to know. This is a bit broad as it stands, and you will get better answers if you are a bit more specific about your needs. What do you typically use Photoshop for?

Comment: For 2D graphics of video games.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Since it's free at worst you will have lost time. Pro tip: Gimp doesn't try to be a PS clone, as they say, it's not Gimp that is hard to learn, it"s PS which is difficult to un-learn. The main thing that you will miss with Gimp is adjustment layers and non-destructive editing (planned for some future release). The main thing that you will gain is freedom.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114222/q-gimp-vs-photoshop -- One of the paramount issues is lack of native CMYK support in GIMP, if that matters to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Q: Gimp vs Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114222/q-gimp-vs-photoshop)

Comment: GIMP is comparable to Photoshop in many ways, however it also differs significantly enough that I'd say it's not a total replacement for Photoshop.  There are pros and cons for each application. There are things PS can do that GIMP can't and vice versa. Check out the proposed duplicate question for more detailed info

Comment: If you are interested in drawing stuff then you should not choose Photoshop or GIMP. They are final preparation tools. You should aim to use some software more suited, like say krita, sketchbook a lot more in this category. If  your purpose is to integrate photographic elements or scans then Gimp and PS are the tools of choice. Doing a feature by feature comparasion is futile. Since GIMP is a better pixel manipulator, but ps is a better graphic design tool. But neither tool is a good drawing or painting environment. They can do it but not really their forte too heavy for the task.

Answer (score 3):

"Overall" is not a good parameter to compare. We would need to make a table comparing specific features.

But I will give my 2 cents. Perhaps these are not a big issue. Perhaps they are.

1. One specific limitation is "Integration". There are competent tools for every application adobe has. Vector drawing, photo editing, video editing, compositing, printing. There are good "combos", but as a complete suite, there is not.

   I personally use a bit PS but I do not often use Illustrator, but Corel Draw. I do not integrate PS with any video or compositing tool either.

---

2. CMYK color mode. Yes, you can live without it for a lot of cases where you actually can leave the color conversion to a later step, but sometimes you cant. For video games, this is not an issue at all. The same for some special channels and preparations for print.

---

3. Masking complex shapes, like hair. This is one thing where I personally use PS more, but for videogames, again, not a big issue.

---

But "Overall," I think you can do most things on Gimp or other programs for that matter, on Paint shop pro, on Affinity photo, Krita, Alpaca, etc. You need to go for the specifics to find a limitation, but I think a lot of them can be overcome.