# How much more processing power does Adobe Photoshop use vs Gimp?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-editing, image-editing, image-processing

Gimp is not only free but is also lightweight and resources compared to Photoshop it feels like. Photoshop's long splash screen makes it feel resource heavy with alot of overhead. Is there technical proof of this?

Finally, why would anyone use Photoshop that's resource-heavy when Gimp can do about every post-processing function it can twice as efficient

Comment: Gimp takes five times longer to load than Photoshop for me. I have both, I only ever touch Gimp to see if I can answer questions in here… which I usually can't.

Comment: @Tetsujin - might depend on your OS. I have GIMP and Photoshop CC, using Windows 10, and GIMP loads in 5 seconds,  Photoshop takes 20 seconds, and for some reason alos takes a while to close on Windows too, compared to GIMP which closes immediately.

Comment: @BillyKerr - Hmm.. just timed them both & Gimp was much faster than I've seen it. Mac. Ps launch 5s, quit 2s. Gimp launch 8s, quit 1s. Not enough to bother me. I've seen it take 30s or longer, maybe it was first run, checking fonts or similar. Ps takes more memory at first launch, but I do have it loaded up with plugins which may have an effect & its 600MB footprint is nothing to the 30GB it can eat when I'm pushing it hard ;)

Comment: Adobes home screen takes a lot of time to load, its essentially just a web framework on top of the software. If you disable it, like i have for illustrator then is shaves 1/2 of the launch time. Mainly because it needs to prefetch a number of thumbnails.

Comment: why use Photoshop? CMYK, amongst other things: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114222/q-gimp-vs-photoshop

Comment: @Luciano if you need CMYK, amongst other things, such as functionality like Smart Objects, you can in fact use Krita.

Comment: @Tetsujin -  on first run, GIMP does a plugin and font scan, and always takes longer. The next run should be much quicker.

Comment: I've now voted to close this too. It's comparing apples to oranges with some kind of unstated agenda in mind. If Ps was substantially inferior to Gimp, no-one at all would use it. I think that's argument enough for its 30-year continued existence [whatever anyone might think of their pricing policy, people do pay it.]

Comment: Why does anyone drive a Lamborghini when a 1982 Yugo does the same thing? Why doe people pay for expensive meals at a restaurant owned by a famous Chef when McDonalds has burgers for 99¢? Silly premise overall. Gimp may be great, but it's not the be-all-end-all, neither is Photoshop for that matter. Use what works *for you*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could measure a lot of things. Chronometer loading time, disk space, and you could look into the Task manager on your computer and see memory consumption and CPU usage.

Loading time is not a good measure because Adobe has as far as I understand a preloader.

Memory consumption either because a program could load more resources, in fact, to work faster. If you have memory available, why not use it?

In the end, the best way to measure this is you have the work done. Do identical tasks, and feel where you are more comfortable. Probably human-delay times are greater than machine ones, for example thinking what to do next, etc.

Comment: You kind of forget that most processes are close to instant these days. I remember way back in the 90s that there was a lot of waiting to do, every time you wanted to process something. Now I get irritated if it takes more than 5 seconds to do anything.

Comment: The first 3D wireframe previews I got some decades ago took all the lunchtime. Not renders... previews... :o)

Comment: Renders were started Friday as you left work… in the hope they would be done by Monday morning when you got back ;)

Comment: Wonder why anyone would use Photoshop that's resource-heavy when Gimp can do about every post-processing function it can twice as efficient

Comment: @Tetsujin there still is stuff like that. I left a calculation over weekend running on 100 computers wasnt finished on monday untill 10:00

Comment: I bet it wasn't a simple rip off of the Star Wars ' A long time ago…' which is what used to take a weekend to render at probably 480p ;)

Comment: @user610620 - familiarity? I've been using Ps for 30 years. I can never find anything in Gimp & have zero incentive to learn it. & I really don't know what you'd call "resource-heavy" on a modern computer. It runs here on either M1 iMacs or decade-old 12-core Mac Pros with 64GB RAM. Neither have any difficulty at all with anything thrown at them. If you're running a cheap laptop with 8GB RAM, then *everything* you do is resource limited, not just Photoshop.

Comment: By resource heavy, meant having access to the same effects on a program that takes longer to start up than a program that can do the exact same effects

Comment: @user610620 I do not know if this is now a real question or just a rant. Why people use Photoshop or Gimp is another question. Which loads faster is really not important.

Comment: @user610620 photoshop is not about effects. If it was gimp would be better but its not. Its about custom channel support, live layer effects, seamless integration with illustrator and indesign... If it was about effects we would be using something like nuke or fusion

Answer (score 0):

Its relatively unimportant. Its not like a person who works with the application for a living ever needs to close it. Hell I do not and  I still have photoshop running from like 7 days ago, along with 2 significantly heavier CAD applications*, illustrator and matlab.

Photoshop is used mainly because of the things gimp does not do. Its true that by iterating things that gimp does it does better. But its not what people are after either. Mostly all adobe applications are about the print support. Ability to natively do PDF files with vector support. And in case of photoshop the killer features are elsewhere like nondestructive edits design layers automated foregound detection etc.

* though creo which is significantly more rescource hungry than PS in general can be tuned to open in 2 seconds faster than PS because the license is on local network.